# Laravel checkbox always save as 1

Tags: laravel

There is checkbox in form

```
{!! Form::checkbox('is_explicit_content', '1', $post->is_explicit_content, ['id' => 'is_explicit_content']); !!} 
{!! Form::label('is_explicit_content', 'Explicit', ['class' => 'checkbox-label']) !!}
```

model

```
class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'text',
        'is_explicit_content'
    ];
}
```

but value is always saved as 1 and I don't understand why? How to fix it?

Comment: Please show us your store method in your controller. The current code looks alright.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a checkbox is submitted, it's value is what's given, but if it's unticked, no such form entry is sent.

If you tick the following and submit your form, `$_POST['foobar']` is set to `1`.

```
<input type='checkbox' name='foobar' value='1' />
```

If you leave it unticked, `$_POST['foobar']` will be unavailable. If you want to have a default value you need to have a hidden input before your checkbox.

```
<input type='hidden' name='foobar' value='0' />
<input type='checkbox' name='foobar' value='1' />
```

Now if you submit the form with `foobar` unticked, the value of `$_POST['foobar']` will be `0`.

Comment: Everyone should learn of this trick :) My mind was blown a few months ago when I tried to work around it.